# Как с помощью RxJava посчитать сумму в Observable<Integer>?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Вот такая простая задача которая не хочет решаться

вот так выглядит

```
Observable<Integer> result = sum(Observable.just(1, 3, 4, 6, 3));

@NonNull
public static Observable<Integer> sum(@NonNull Observable<Integer> observable)
{
    return Observable.just(0);
}
```

Пробовал писаться `sumInteger()` но не распознает этот метод

Как нужно написать метод, чтоб он возвращал сумму всех чисел?

Answer (score 4):

`sumInteger()` - метод класса `MathObservable` входящего в `rxjava-math`. Если эта библиотека есть в зависимостях, то можно так:

```
Observable<Integer> numbers = Observable.just(1, 3, 4, 6, 3);

Integer result = MathObservable.sumInteger(numbers)
                   .toBlocking()
                   .firstOrDefault(0);
```

А можно и без неё:

```
Integer result = numbers.reduce(0, new Func2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }
})
.toBlocking()
.firstOrDefault(0);
```

Или проще, если код только для Android 7, где поддерживаются лямбды:

```
Integer result = numbers.reduce(0, Integer::sum)
                   .toBlocking()
                   .firstOrDefault(0);
```

Comment: _"если код только для Android 7, где поддерживаются лямбды"_ - эм.. в джаве поддержка лямбд происходит в рантайме, а не при компиляции?

Comment: @Qwertiy Android Studio выдаст ошибку "Lambda expressions are not supported at this language level", если API Level ниже 24-го. И в документации написано, что возможности Java 8 поддерживаются только с Android 7.

Comment: а еще есть https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda